# jQuery: How to create a live search form with multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, radio-button

Let's assume, a database contains entries for cars in many models, colours and with 2, 4 and 5 doors.

**The task:** *Create a search form which lets the user pick both model, colour and number of doors, using only radio buttons. Every time the user selects a radio button, the search result should be updated. No Submit-Button.*

**The HTML-Code:**

```
<form id="searchform">
  <div>
  <input id="car_model1" type="radio" name="model" value="bmw"> BMW
  <input id="car_model2" type="radio" name="model" value="peugeot"> Peugeot
  <input id="car_model3" type="radio" name="model" value="fiat"> Fiat
  </div>

  <div>
  <input id="car_colour1" type="radio" name="colour" value="white"> White
  <input id="car_colour2" type="radio" name="colour" value="red"> Red
  <input id="car_colour3" type="radio" name="colour" value="blue"> Blue
  </div>

  <div>
  <input id="car_door1" type="radio" name="door" value="2"> Two
  <input id="car_door2" type="radio" name="door" value="4"> Four
  <input id="car_door3" type="radio" name="door" value="5"> Five
  </div>
</form>

<div id="searchresult"></div>
```

Now, I thought, I could use the jQuery change() function to catch the users click and then send a request via post() to the database. But somehow I can't make it work. Here is my attempt:

**The Javascript-Code**

```
$("[id^=car]").change(function() {
  var data = $("#searchform").serialize();
  $.post("process_data.php", data, function(response) {
    $("#searchresult").html(response);
  });
});
```

Of course there is PHP-Code to process the request, but the problem is that the Javascript is not executed. The change-Event does not work. I also tried it with click() and keyup(). Same negative result.

I am quite new to jQuery and Ajax and right now I have no idea what is wrong. Maybe you can tell me where my error is.

Comment: Provide some more details. What is displaying in the console.? Any errors.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another day and after a good sleep I tried it again and this time I found the source of the problem: I load the script in the `<head>` part of my HTML. Therefore I need to make sure, the document is fully loaded, using the ready() function, otherwise the change() function does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^=car]").change(function() {
    var data = $("#searchform").serialize();
    $.post("process_data.php", data, function(response) {
      $("#searchresult").html(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,

```
$("input[id^=car]").change(function() {
```

I will not say that your `selector` is wrong. But using an `element name` before the `attribute selector` is a good practice.

Fiddle : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UXCQD/)